# pip install modules/packages for AWS Lambda functions cross-platform

Tags: python, aws-lambda, pip

I'm using pip 22.3.1 on a Windows host, but, of course similar issues are present on MacOS. When trying to assemble PyPI packages to be used in an AWS Lambda function, which executes in a Linux environment, one wants to be sure the correct packages are used for Linux.

From my vantage point, over the years, pip has been more and more difficult to get it to do this. It is so crabby complaining combinations of command line options.

Nominally, one would like to do this:
`pip install -r requirements.txt --target .\lib --platform linux --python-version 3.9`

But, of course it complains that it can't have the --user argument along with --target. Of course, --user is absent. So, I have to add --no-user. Then it complains that restricting platform and interpreter constraints using --python-version and --platform requires that you supply either: (1) --no-deps or (2) --only-binary=:all:.

With case #2, trying to install jinja2==3.1.2 results in the complaint that a version could not be found for MarkupSafe. Why? Well it is not a binary package. Am I supposed to run pip multiple times?

So, I can use approach 1, and I can manually put dependencies of other packages in requirements.txt. Is there an easier way?

Or is there a better solution to this problem? I used to be able to do this with pip not that long ago without issue.

Comment: A better approach is to do `pip install` in docker or an EC2 instance that has similar environment as lambda.

Comment: "*…over the years, pip has been more and more difficult to get it to do [cross-platform downloading]…*" Because nobody does it cross-platform these days. Containers, emulators and virtual hosts are available freely or cheap enough. Run `pip` natively, that's the solution!